# Why the post ID is 0 in a hook within wp_insert_post_data?

Tags: hooks

I am having trouble getting the ID of the post in a function applied to the `wp_insert_post_data` filter. It is actually zero.

To clarify I am getting the `$postarr` and the value of the `ID` field is 0. (meaning number of parameters is correct, 2, in the `add_filter` declaration)

What can cause this?

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can provide? Also, are you inserting a new post or updating a post?

Comment: I am inserting a new post, I am testing the code with just error_log in the function and it returns the whole `$postarr` and in it the `ID` is 0 the rest of the array is ok, it has content,title, etc

Comment: The post id has not been generated yet when the `wp_insert_post_data` is called. If you look at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3219 the post_id is set at line 3219 but the filter is used at line 3182

Comment: So the `$postarr['ID']` is available only when updating posts and not inserting new ones I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As deduced from the comments, and the source code, the `ID` for new posts is only generated after the hook `wp_insert_post_data`, the wordpress codex is misleading in this regard.